# How to convert string value into number

Tags: java, postgresql-9.2

My table is
here `Loan_Time` field is a `string` field. I want it to convert to a number

```
||Loan_Time  ||   || Approve_amt||
|| 3 Year    ||   ||      15000.00||
```

I want it like this

```
||Loan_Time|| ||Approve_amt||
||   36    || ||15000.00||
```

How can i do it?

Comment: @YCF_L it _can_ be if you convert it to months

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
UPDATE table SET Loan_time=SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Loan_time, ' Year', 1), 1, 2)*12
```

Please test the command on a test server to make sure it works as expected. I have accounted for years greater than 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching:

```
String original = "3 Year";
int months = 0;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s.+").matcher(original);
if (m.find()) {
    months = 12 * Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(months); //update the DB with these months
```